# Bootstrap 3 Table with filter, size of multiple select input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a static table with the following row structure:

1. Head
2. Multiple select to filter items
3. Data rows

Is it possible to make (2):

a) Dropdown with multiple selects
b) Ensure that inner text in multiple selects is truncated so size is dictated by the rest of the rows

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>head1</th>
                <th>head2</th>
                <th>head3</th>
                <th>head4</th>
                <th>head5</th>
                <th>head6</th>
                <th>head7</th>
                <th>head8</th>
                <th>head9</th>
                <th>head10</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <select multiple class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option value="jan">Jan Foo Lorem Ipsum</option>
                            <option value="feb">Feb</option>
                            <option value="mar">Mar</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <select multiple class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option value="jan">Jan Foo Lorem Ipsum</option>
                            <option value="feb">Feb</option>
                            <option value="mar">Mar</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <select multiple class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option value="jan">Jan Foo Lorem Ipsum</option>
                            <option value="feb">Feb</option>
                            <option value="mar">Mar</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <select multiple class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option value="jan">Jan Foo Lorem Ipsum</option>
                            <option value="feb">Feb</option>
                            <option value="mar">Mar</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <select multiple class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option value="jan">Jan Foo Lorem Ipsum</option>
                            <option value="feb">Feb</option>
                            <option value="mar">Mar</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <select multiple class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option value="jan">Jan Foo Lorem Ipsum</option>
                            <option value="feb">Feb</option>
                            <option value="mar">Mar</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <select multiple class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option value="jan">Jan Foo Lorem Ipsum</option>
                            <option value="feb">Feb</option>
                            <option value="mar">Mar</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <select multiple class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option value="jan">Jan Foo Lorem Ipsum</option>
                            <option value="feb">Feb</option>
                            <option value="mar">Mar</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <select multiple class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option value="jan">Jan Foo Lorem Ipsum</option>
                            <option value="feb">Feb</option>
                            <option value="mar">Mar</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <select multiple class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option value="jan">Jan Foo Lorem Ipsum</option>
                            <option value="feb">Feb</option>
                            <option value="mar">Mar</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>7543</td>
                <td>6148</td>
                <td>1006004</td>
                <td>0200000100018</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>0200000100018 0200000100018 0,6x4</td>
                <td>0,6x4</td>
                <td>0,6</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>0,1</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

A fiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bbad3e5f/2/)
I am using Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filtering in the table, use datatables plugin.
[Data tables](https://datatables.net)